# Instruments OSSignpost intervals not recording or displaying

Tags: swift, logging, instruments, signpost, oslog

I'm trying to use OSSignposter to capture intervals in our app for use in Instruments. The sample code here works in a new project. I see the intervals, signpost icons, etc. However, this same code (integrated into a much bigger app does not record or display ANY intervals.

I can get the config status on both apps' oslog configuration, and there's no difference.

```
sudo log config --status --subsystem **.*******.*******.signposttest
Mode for '**.*******.*******.signposttest'  INFO PERSIST_DEFAULT
```

I've checked both workspaces and schemes. There is no difference between these projects. The only thing I can think of at this point is a build setting that could affect it. (I'm not using OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = disable).

Perhaps it's a provision profile issue? Entitlements? However, I've tried profiling in debug mode with debug provision profile and got the same results.

Not seeing any signpost activity is happening in `immediate mode` and `deferred mode`. I see events in the bottom pane in "List: Events" view. In the `last n seconds mode`, there is no data, no lanes, and nothing on the timeline.

Here's the sample code. I tried in both projects.

```swift
import os.signpost

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var blackWindow: UIWindow?
    var alertWindow: UIWindow?
    static var originalAppDelegate: AppDelegate!

    var signposter: OSSignposter
    var signpostInterval: OSSignpostIntervalState?

    override init() {
        signposter = OSSignposter(subsystem: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier ?? "unknown", category: "app")
        signposter.emitEvent(#function)
    }


  func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        guard let interval =  signpostInterval else {
            assertionFailure("no interval")
            return
        }
        print("backgrounding, ending active state")
        signposter.endInterval("active", interval)
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        signpostInterval = signposter.beginInterval("active")
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }
}
```

This is what I expect to see, signposts and intervals.

[image: working signpost]

However, this is the sample code run in the non-working project.

[image]

---

### Update

If I programmatically check if the OSSignposter is enabled, I get `false`. I have no idea how this has been disabled externally, as I'm not explicitly disabling OSSignposter. I also do not see a way to programmatically enabled it.

```swift
signposter = OSSignposter(subsystem: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier ?? "unknown", category: category)
assert(signposter.isEnabled)
```

This always asserts.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Try heading into your Scheme and adding this environment variable.  This should fix the assert issue and hopefully also create some traces in Instruments.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, I was able to make the signpost intervals appear in Instruments by specifying `category: .pointsOfInterest`.

```swift
let signposter = OSSignposter(subsystem: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier ?? "unknown", category: .pointsOfInterest)
```

This also made `signposter.isEnabled` return true. Other values for the `category` parameter didn't seem to work (neither strings nor other `OSLog.Category` values).